# wrapping h264 stream into mp4 with gstreamer

Tags: video, h.264, mp4, gstreamer

how can I wrap pure h.264 stream into mp4 using Gstreamer so that I can seek to specific location in video? Gstreamer is used because of it's licence requirements, so please do not offer ffmpeg!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=stream.h264 ! video/x-h264 ! h264parse ! mp4mux ! filesink location=video.mp4
```

Comment: Ok, this gives me error from `h264parse0: GStreamer encountered a general stream error.` and `streaming stopped, reason not-negotiated`.

Comment: gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=stream.h264 ! video/x-h264 ! h264parse ! mp4mux ! filesink location=video.mp4

Comment: In gstreamer 1.16 this gives "ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstMP4Mux:mp4mux0: Could not multiplex stream."

Comment: @user1145922 see previous comment (and now updated example). From gst-inspect-1.0 for both h264parse and mp4mux you can see that the pad templates are compatible. If it does not work for you please post a gist with the fiull log output.

Comment: @ensonic I think the problem I was having was caused by the file I was using not actually being a .h264 file even though it was labeled as such. It was really a MPEG-2 TS with a h264 stream in it.

Comment: Thanks for the update. When you are not sure about the content, give gst-discoverer-1.0 a try.